# Missing compilation symbols when publishing Asp Net Core project

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I have recently made new build configurations for my asp net core project. Everything works when I run locally but when I publish to Azure the compilation symbols I defined for any build configuration are missing. I know this because I am hitting the below NotSupportedException. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#if DB_MEMORY
    services.AddDbContext<ClimbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Test"));
#elif DB_LOCAL
    services.AddDbContext<ClimbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("local")));
#elif DB_AZURE
    services.AddDbContext<ClimbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection")));
#else
    throw new System.NotSupportedException("Need to assign a DB type.");
#endif
```

[Project Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN0aY.png)

[.csproj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9NFE.png)

[Publish Profile Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sdmM.png)